# Anaconda 1.10 - what is the "Anaconda" environment?

Tags: anaconda

I installed Anaconda 1.10 (Win 10 Home, 64-bit, 20H2; with installer Anaconda3-2020.11-Windows-x86_64)

This was a fresh installation and I notice that whereas I previously had a default "base" env, there are now "base" and "Anaconda(?3)" envs listed in the environment list GUI - but when I try to activate ~Anaconda it says there is no such environment and listing environments in the command window also shows there is no such environment.

Obvious internet searches did not turn up an answer (it may be there but drowned in the non-specific terms "base environment", "anaconda environment", etc.)

What is it? Is it an environment or not, what is its purpose and how should I use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems related to previously raised issues on GitHub [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8623)

There are two places where Anaconda *might* create environments, C:\Users[username].conda\envs and (the primary location) C:\Users[username]\Anaconda3\envs).

My installation is not creating in .conda\envs but it was listing environments created in the primary location in C:\Users[username].conda\environments.txt

Renaming/removing this file a) resolves the issue and b) seems to have no adverse effect elsewhere.

Update: the file may be recreated, but (strangely) in such a way that duplicates no longer appear.

No obvious cause found in accessible preferences, etc.